# password using adduser --system while setting up OpenERP

Tags: ubuntu, odoo

I followed the guide for installing OpenERP [here](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) and did this:

```
 sudo adduser --system --home=/opt/openerp --group openerp
```

Can somebody tell me what the password for this is?

I'm pretty sure I didn't set a password for this but the system prompts me for openerp password at certain stages in the installation.

I've already tried my root password and it doesn’t work !

Comment: I got a workaround for my problem and i used sudo passwd openerp to change the openerp user password using my root account. The OpenERP is set up and working fine now. I would still like to know how openerp got a password without me having set one in the first place. I've come across this piece of info extensively that linux systems don't set a default password.